# Dictionary Object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I'm trying to create a dictionary object in Ruby and get it to pass a bunch of RSPEC tests as part of a project. So far it's been good, but I'm stuck on one particular test. Here's the RSPEC up until that test:

```
require 'dictionary'

describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it 'is empty when created' do
    @d.entries.should == {}
  end

  it 'can add whole entries with keyword and definition' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end

  it 'add keywords (without definition)' do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => nil}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end

  it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false
  end

  it "doesn't cheat when checking whether a given keyword exists" do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false # if the method is empty, this test passes with nil returned
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.include?('fish').should be_true # confirms that it actually checks
    @d.include?('bird').should be_false # confirms not always returning true after add
  end
end
```

Everything passes so far except for the last test "doesn't cheat when checking whether a given keyword exists". I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can get that to pass, but so far no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Dictionary
  attr_accessor :keywords, :entries
  def initialize 
    @entries = {}
     end
 def add(defs)
    defs.each do |word, definition|
      @entries[word] = definition
    end
  end
  def keywords
    input = []
    @entries.each do |key, value|
    input << key
    end
    input.sort  
  end
  def  include?(key)
    self.keywords.include?(keywords.to_s) 
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which one among "doesn't cheat when checking whether a given keyword exists" fails?

Comment: Forgive me if this is rude, but may I ask what the point of this object is?  I don't see any functionality that isn't provided by Hash..

Comment: You neglect to mention how it fails.

Comment: +1 @totallymike, I'd just use `class Dictionary < Hash; end` and adjust the methods if any needed changes.

Comment: Which particular test is failing. A test is a line with a should statement, not what you define via if. That is called a testcase.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry @sawa.  The failure is coming on the @d.include?('bird').should be_false

Comment: Maybe he is doing that for educational purposes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in:

```
self.keywords.include?(keywords.to_s)
```

`keywords` returns an array. You can't use `keywords.to_s` as a parameter for `keywords.include?` and expect it to find a match:

```
irb(main):002:0> keywords = %w[a b c]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
irb(main):003:0> keywords.to_s
=> "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
irb(main):004:0> keywords.include?(keywords.to_s)
=> false
irb(main):005:0> keywords.include?('a')
=> true
```

because you need to use an individual element in the `keywords` array if you want to find it. Notice that `keywords.to_s` is a String-ized version of the array, which could also be: `'["a", "b", "c"]'`. Hopefully that will help you recognize the problem the next time you encounter it.

From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) for `include?`:

```
  a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
  a.include?("b")   #=> true
  a.include?("z")   #=> false
```

So, change:

```
  def  include?(key)
    self.keywords.include?(keywords.to_s) 
  end
```

to:

```
  def  include?(key)
    self.keywords.include?(key) 
  end
```

What do you mean by "doesn't cheat"? How can code cheat? It only does what you told it. All the previous tests look like they'd rule out the conditions being tested in the "doesn't cheat" block which makes only:

```
@d.include?('bird').should be_false # confirms not always returning true after add
```

worth including in it. You could use:

```
@d.add('fish')
@d.include?('bird').should be_false # confirms not always returning true after add
```

if you really aren't sure how your code works.

Instead of building `keywords` using an array, which will get slower the larger your `@entries` list is, and results in `include?` running slower any time you call it,
take advantage of the fact that `@entries` is already a hash and use its methods:

```
def keywords
  @entries.keys.sort
end

def include?(key)
  !!@entries[key]
end
```

Or use this for `include?`:

```
def include?(key)
  @entries.key?(key)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As totallymike mentions in the comment, most of the functions you want already exist in `Hash`. For the slightly different interfaces that you want, you should inherit `Hash`.

```
class Dictionary < Hash
  def add(defs)
    defs = {defs => nil} unless defs.kind_of?(Hash)
    merge!(defs)
  end
  alias entries dup
  def keywords; keys.sort end
end
```

Comment: @Joshua You added `entries`, which is useless under this implementation that uses a subclass. And you incorrectly replaced the definition of `keywords` into a one that does not `sort`.

Comment: It needs entries to pass the spec, and there is nothing in the spec about the keys being sorted.

Comment: @sawa, wow thank you. That answer has really got me thinking in a whole new way about existing classes in Ruby. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you an idea how to get to pass "doesn't cheat when checking whether a given keyword exists"?

```
@h = Hash.new{|h,k,v| h[k] = nil}
@h["fish"]
p @h #=> {"fish"=>nil}
```

The `{|h,k,v| h[k] = nil}`part is run when a key is *not* present in the hash. It adds the key and gives it a nil value.